# Increase string 0.00 by x percent

Tags: c#, string

I need to increase string like '0.3332 USD', '12.5334 USD', '6.2222 USD' by x percent, how can i convert these strings to numeric format xxx.xx example '0.33', '12.53', '6.22'

I tried this, but its worng method
     String cmprice = result.Substring(0, x);

Answer (score 2):

You could use `decimal.TryParse` with the proper `NumberFormatInfo`:

```
string dollars = "0.3332 USD";
decimal price;
var nfi = (NumberFormatInfo)NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo.Clone();
nfi.CurrencySymbol = "USD";
bool validFormat = decimal.TryParse(dollars, NumberStyles.Currency, nfi, out price);
if (validFormat)
{ 
    // apply your percent logic, f.e.:
    decimal newPrice = price + (price * 0.15m); // + 15%  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that the string will ALWAYS end in "USD", you can create a substring that is four characters short of the full string, then parse it.

```
String cmprice = result.Substring(0, result.Length - 4);
decimal parsedResult;
decimal.TryParse(cmprice, out parsedResult);
```